# how to count how many times I clicked my image button * LUA *

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I've created hello world text and a clickable button. When I click the button the hello world jumps around randomly.

The problem: I don't know how to get my program to count how many times i've clicked the button.

My progress:

```
local myHeight = display.contentHeight
local myWidth = display.contentWidth

local topRightHeight = display.newText ("Height "..myHeight, 300 , 40 ,nil,15)
local topRightWidth = display.newText ("Width "..myWidth, 300,60,nil,15) 


local redButton = display.newImage ("button.png",0,0)
redButton.x = display.contentWidth -60
redButton.y = display.contentHeight -62.5


local textObj = display.newText ("Hello World",0,0,native.systemFont,18)
textObj: setFillColor(0,250,0)
textObj.x = 40
textObj.y = 30



local number = 0


number = display.newText (number, 30, 30 , native.systemFont, 25)



function moveButtonRandom (event)
textObj.x = math.random(50, display.contentWidth -50)
textObj.y = math.random(50, display.contentHeight -50)

end


redButton: addEventListener ("tap", moveButtonRandom)
```

Comment: Why you tagged this Question with `iOS` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use flag of int type to count the number of times button clicked.

Initially set flag=0 and if button is clicked then inside onclick() method use flag=flag+1.

Comment: What @S S K has said is spot on. Code (line by line):

`local flag = 0`
`function moveButtonRandom (event)`
`flag = flag + 1`
`print("Button tap count: "..tostring(flag))`
`textObj.x = math.random(50, display.contentWidth -50)`
`textObj.y = math.random(50, display.contentHeight -50)`
`end`

Comment: I'm confused about the on click()method, can you explain that more in detail. I'm also getting number stacking on each other.

Answer (score 1):

Now it works like a charm

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

local redButton = display.newImage ("button.png",0,0)
redButton.x = display.contentWidth - 60
redButton.y = display.contentHeight - 62.5

local textObj = display.newText("Hello World", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 18)
textObj:setFillColor(0, 250, 0)
textObj.x = 40
textObj.y = 30


local number = 0
local textField = display.newText(number, 30, 30, native.systemFont, 25)

local function moveButtonRandom(event)
    textObj.x = math.random(50, display.contentWidth - 50)
    textObj.y = math.random(50, display.contentHeight - 50)
    number = number + 1
    textField:removeSelf()
    textField = display.newText(number, 30, 30, native.systemFont, 25)
end

redButton:addEventListener("tap", moveButtonRandom)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track the click on monitoring some flag in your `clickListener` for button. Maintain a  flag increment it whenever you clicked on your button through clickListener. Some thing like this

intialize a variable let say `int flagForButton = 0` in your activity

```
OnClickListener clickListener1 = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    flagForButton++;
        Toast.makeText(MarketSnap.this, String.valueOf(flagForButton), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Set the clickListener on the button. Like this

```
yourbutton.setOnClickListener(clickListener1);
```

**EDIT**

While answering this question the question was tagged with `Android`. So i have put the code as above. But Now the question is edited and tagged as `LUA`. So the logic remain same you can increment the `flagcount` in `clickListener` Of the the button.

Comment: Thanks for effort, you have the right strategy, but the OP requires lua and corona SDK, not java and android SDK (although they would probably be able to translate ;)

Comment: @Schollii hmmm when i have answered this question it was tagged as Android. As i see the question is edited now. So i can make change. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Update text number on every click. No need to delete it and create it again.

local number = 0
local textField = display.newText(number, 30, 30, native.systemFont, 25)

local function updateNumber(n)

textField.text = n

end

local function moveButtonRandom(event)

```
textObj.x = math.random(50, display.contentWidth - 50)

textObj.y = math.random(50, display.contentHeight - 50)

number = number + 1

UpdateNumber(number)
```

end

redButton:addEventListener("tap", moveButtonRandom)